# 3 points determine a plane - but not 3 vertices?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I am trying to patch the hole using the fill command. It will not work selecting either the 3 edges or the 3 vertices. Any ideas what to try?

Thank you-
[image]

Comment: Go into Wireframe mode and lasso/rubberband select the bottom vertex - I bet there's another right underneath it.  Then merge the two verts and I bet the fill will work.

Comment: Yup looks like the North West > South edge is actually linked to 2 other double vertices since it isn't highlighted in orange

Comment: Yes, as the others say, if the selected vertex at the bottom of the triangle would be connected to those two edges going to the left, they would be highlighted in orange. So there is no hole to fill.